# How to allow CORS in google cloud run?

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-run, flask-cors

I have a react microservice (via nginx) deployed onto google cloud run with its environment variable for the backend set to another google cloud run instance that's running gunicorn which is serving the backend.

My Flask app is set up following everything I could find about allowing CORS:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
return app

# Different file, a blueprint's urls:

@blueprint.route('/resources')
@cross_origin()
def get_resources():
...
```

Yet I'm still getting the dreaded `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend/resources/' from origin 'https://frontend' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Does anyone have any insight into this/know where else to look in figuring this out? I wanted to set up GKE with my microservices but took the path of least resistance initially to get a POC up in the cloud. I have the backend speaking with my Cloud SQL instance, and I'm so close!!

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a minimal Dockerfile / app.py that reproduces this when deployed to Cloud Run?

Comment: Yes I can try to when I have some more time, hopefully tonight. 

One thing that's interesting is that if i curl -I the backend w/ my resource (https://backend/resources), I do see the allow cors in the header but I'm getting a 404 from the server as a response?

Comment: 404s were my  fault. Now it seems like Cloud Run is doing a permanent redirect (308) to the same endpoint (http s://backend/resources -> http ://backend/resources)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything was self inflicted.

As Dustin Ingram mentioned, if you enable CORS for Flask, it will work. I still have NO idea why I was getting the CORS issues at all, I've had CORS enabled for my Flask app from the get go.

After I nuked everything and redeployed, the CORS issues disappeared. However, I still ended up getting either 404s, 405s, and 308s.

There were a couple of issues, all my shortcomings, that in combination gave me those issues. In create-react-app  (webpack I think is doing it), environment variables passed into the docker runtime does not get respected, so the environment variable I set in Cloud Run wasn't working at all. Currently I opted for the process.env.VARIABLE || 'hardcoded-url' route. Once I got that figured out, I also remembered trailing slashes in flask URLs are bad.... Those gave me 308s, permanent redirects. Once I got that figured out, I realized during my manual deployments, I wasn't switching the cloud build image to the latest. Sigh. Once I started deploying the latest images, everything started working. Yay!

Thanks Dustin and Gabe for spending your time on my foolishness.

Answer (score 6):

You've set up more than you need to. Unless you need to provide different CORS access for different endpoints, the simplest example just requires calling `CORS(app)`:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/resources")
def get_resources():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080, debug=True)
```

And you'll see that the header is present:

```
$ curl -I localhost:8080/resources
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 26
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.7.4
Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 17:19:25 GMT
```

Comment: Yes I had CORS issues locally and I initially had set up the flask_cors like you mentioned, and it worked locally. It's just now putting it up in Google Cloud Run seems to be either stripping that from the header or blocking it in some shape..

Comment: Cloud Run itself won't remove this header. Is it possible your nginx configuration is removing it?

Comment: Check my answer Dustin...I had issues with this too and NOTHING I did on the server side fixed it... The clue on my end (oh, and mcIslee this is something to check) was that curl worked...but not my web app. So switched the http request lib I was using (fetch) back for normal xhttp and it all started workin. Some bad interaction tickled it just right. Don't know if this is the same, but that's what got it working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently wrestled with this as well... My issue was trying to use some JS library to make my URL requests "easier" and instead was munging the headers on the request side (not the server side). Switched to just using straight XMLHttp and it started working fine. I also switched from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I don't know if that made a difference or not, but including it for completeness.

You also shouldn't (I say shouldn't, but you know how that goes) need anything OTHER than:

CORS(app). All the @cross-region stuff, and the config pieces are all only there to make a narrower CORS access so it's not wide open, but you have it wide open anyway in your initial code (`CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})` is the same I believe as `CORS(app)`).

Long story, short, try looking at the request object, rather than the Flask side.

Edit: Adding the request code that worked for me after I couldn't get the "fetch" library working:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", <url>, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xhttp.send(Data)
```

Comment: Do you have any resources/links I can look into for what you mean by making the request "easier?" Yes haha I figured making the CORS wrap the whole app object would be the most permissive option, but I decided to put everything from the kitchen sink to see if/when it would work.

Comment: I was trying to use the "fetch" library. It has a simpler syntax for making requests which felt like a nicety. But no matter what I tweaked, I wasn't able to make it work. I'll add the code for the request I used which worked.

Comment: Hm I tried your snippet, built frontend locally pointed at the backend and still getting CORS :( . Will try deploying the frontend w/ the same settings and see if that does anything differently

Comment: The snippet in the frontend cloud run instance no longer gets CORS errors... now getting 404s though lol I must have something configured wrong -.-

Comment: Huh...and you removed the @cross-origin tag from the route entrypoints?

Comment: Yes, but the 404s were my mistake. No more cors, no more 404s... Now getting a http mixed content (https -> http) error for the API resource lol. Looking at the network traffic it looks like the server is redirecting to http?

Comment: Woah that's odd...I'm afraid we're starting to dip into areas I'm definitely NOT an expert in. :)

Comment: Haha no worries, I got it all figured it out. Explained in the answer I self-posted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was solved by setting Allow unauthenticated invocations in Cloud Run. However, this should only be done with testing and for a production environment you'll have to configure Cloud IAM.