# Gcloud Angular 6 app deployment taking extremely long

Tags: web-deployment, gcloud

I was trying to deploy my angular project to gCloud and after following the steps mentioned here https://medium.com/@st_yuri/how-to-deploy-an-angular-8-application-and-a-python-3-flask-restplus-api-on-google-cloud-using-ebbed60e665f
and running the following command.

```
 gcloud app deploy
```

my Application started deploying but it's going extremely slow and for some reason I see that there are 32000 files being uploaded. This being the first deployment, is this normal or did I miss something. It's been running for 3 hours now and has made very little progress.

My app.yaml file is as follows

```
runtime: python37
api_version: 1
handlers:
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your guide, you have to add `skip_files` section in your app.yaml. Something like:

```
skip_files:
  - node_modules/
  - ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
```

I suggest you that guide https://dev.to/marwan01/deploy-an-angular-app-using-google-cloud-run-3p4a I used recently.

On Google Cloud you use `Cloud Run`

You have to create Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('dist/PROJECT-NAME'));
app.get('/', function (req, res,next) {
res.redirect('/');
});
app.listen(8080)
```

Then with https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/SERVICE-NAME
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/PROJECT-NAME --platform managed
```

That it.

node_modules is your 32000 files.
Take a look at Section #5 from that guide. There are .dockerignore with node_modules on it. That mean you will not upload that on cloud.

If you will use that guide and got any questions, I can assist.

Comment: Sure thank you for the suggestions I'll try it out and get back to you in case I have any doubts. Will accept this answer once I'm able to see my deployment through. Thanks!

Comment: Is there something similar available to deploy by python backend code too? Also, Thanks a lot! This really helped.

Comment: I belive you use flask as python server? https://medium.com/@doedotdev/docker-flask-a-simple-tutorial-bbcb2f4110b5 you probably have to make DockerFile like int that tutorial, and instead of server.js you will create app.py. Everything other should works like you did for Angular

Comment: Yup, using flask as python server, will try out the same steps for that also. Two questions: 1) How do I make the angular app refer to the flask API route?
2) If I have to push any new code will I have to follow this entire process again?

Comment: also, when I run the "gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/PROJECT-NAME --platform managed" command for my angular deployment. it gives this error: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You can deploy thru console, after you did build. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/run then select your service, and `Edit & Deploy new revision` and select new container under `Container image URL *`, then `Deploy` button.

Comment: About python question, I am not familar with that languaga nad Flask, but for sure you can create routes there, and then after you deploy you will got url of your flask app, that you have to use inside of angular one. Probably it will require to setup CORS on flask or gcloud, check that out https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347316/how-to-allow-cors-in-google-cloud-run